# Yii2 theme integration

Tags: yii2

I have installed Yii2 advanced application, and now I want to change backend theme. 
How can I do this?
Is there any file where I need to tell Yii2 that use my custom theme? 
I established my theme under `backend/web/themes/mytheme`.
I just replaced this code in `advanced/backend/config/main.php`, but nothing happened!

```
 'view' => [
  'theme' => [
       'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/mytheme'],
       'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/mytheme',
    ],
  ],
```

Then I replaced this code under `common/config/main.php` but nothing changed!

Comment: Go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133379/how-can-i-customize-yii2-theme/25260008#25260008). We have already solved this.

Comment: I'm talking about yii2 advanced application theme.

Comment: this is about advanced application in yii2. you apply these steps for backend directory(as u want).

Comment: @sprytechies If you're linking to any existing SO question, then please **flag** the question, where you put that link, as _duplicate_ (done this). Thanks.

Comment: you shall also create a folder layouts inside your backend\web\themes\mytheme\ folder. Then create a main.php file insdie layouts folder and place the your theme header and footer section which for content, just write this line: <?PHP echo $content; ?>

Comment: New answer's are most welcome!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yet another approach to change theme in Yii2 is:

1. Create a themes directory in web folder in frontend or backend where you want to change theme.
2. place your theme folder inside themes directory.
3. change $css and $js variables in AppAsset.php in assets folder in frontend or backend like:

   ```
   public $css = [
       //'css/site.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/font-awesome.min.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/slicknav.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/style.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/responsive.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/animate.css',
       'themes/theme_folder/css/colors/red.css',
       //'themes/margo/asset/css/bootstrap.min.css',
   ];
   public $js = [
           'themes/theme_folder/js/jquery.migrate.js',
           'themes/theme_folder/js/modernizrr.js',
           'themes/theme_folder/js/jquery.fitvids.js',
           'themes/theme_folder/js/owl.carousel.min.js',
           'themes/theme_folder/js/nivo-lightbox.min.js',
           //'themes/theme_folder/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
           //'themes/theme_folder/asset/js/bootstrap.min.js'
   ];
   ```
4. Do not include core bootstrap css, bootstrap js and jquery js as these are core APIs that are provided by Yii2. I have commented them above.
5. Use the below code to reference theme resources (css, js, images etc) in your main.php layout file or other site pages:

   ```
       <?= Yii::getAlias('@web/themes/theme_folder') ?>/images/margo.png
   ```
6. There is no need to include css or js files in layouts->main.php file :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will do this.

Comment: Using your method of theme integration this function is not working `$this->theme->baseurl` ;)

Answer (score 6):

Create a view folder in your `themes/mytheme` and move all view files like `main.php` into it and other layouts needed.

Also you can set your basic layout in the `backend\config\main.php` like

```
return [
'id' => 'app-backend',
'layout'=>'yourtheme', //your `themes/mytheme/views/` contain yourtheme.php in this case
...
```

Also change `pathmap` to

```
 'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/mytheme/views'],
```

Comment: It works for me, change "config/main.php"
'layout'=>'@webroot/themes/mytheme/views/layouts/main.php', 
'pathMap'   => ['@app/views' => '@webroot/themes/mytheme/views'],

Answer (score 4):

In the backend folder make a theme folder .In file backend/config/main.php the components section add the code given below ,files in this folder will behave like the view folder in backend .

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@backend/themes/demo',
                'baseUrl' => '@backend/themes/demo',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@backend/views' => '@backend/themes/demo',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 4):

To install a new backend or frontend theme ( I did one page Bootstrap theme), please follow the below steps:

1. Copy the theme content i.e. directories like js, css, images, fonts etc to for instance backend->web folder.
2. Change your backend->assets->AppAsset.php class i.e. modify $css and $js arrays like

   ```
   public $css = [
       //'css/site.css',
       'css/font-awesome.min.css',
       'css/main.css',
       'css/prettyPhoto.css',
       'css/bootstrap.min.css',
   ];
   public $js = [
           //'js/bootstrap.min.js',
           'js/html5shiv.js',
           'js/jquery.isotope.min.js',
           //'js/jquery.js',
           'js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js',
           'js/main.js',
           'js/respond.min.js',
   ];
   ```

Please keep in mind to comment out core JQuery and Bootstrap JS files as they are provided by Yii2 by default.

3. Modify the backend->views->layouts->main.php file as under:

   ```
    <?php

    /* @var $this \yii\web\View */
    /* @var $content string */

    use backend\assets\AppAsset;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
    use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
    use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
    use common\widgets\Alert;
    use webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\User;
    use webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule;

    AppAsset::register($this);
    ?>

   <?php $this->beginPage() ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
   <head>
   <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="author" content="">
   <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
   <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>

   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
   <script src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/ico/favicon.ico">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
   <?php $this->head() ?>
   </head><!--/head-->

   <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-offset="0">

   <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

       <header id="header" role="banner">
       <div class="container">
           <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
               </div>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#main-slider"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>


                       <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </header><!--/#header-->



               <?= $content ?>



   <footer id="footer">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                   &copy; 2013 <a target="_blank" href="http://shapebootstrap.net/" title="Free Twitter Bootstrap WordPress Themes and HTML templates">ShapeBootstrap</a>. All Rights Reserved.
               </div>
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <img class="pull-right" src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/images/shapebootstrap.png" alt="ShapeBootstrap" title="ShapeBootstrap">
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </footer><!--/#footer-->


   <?php $this->endBody() ?>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php $this->endPage() ?>
   ```
4. Now adjust your other content pages according to theme, place sections of the theme on your pages that suits you :)

Let me know if anyone comes across any difficulty :)

Comment: Yet another clean approach at: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/install-new-theme-in-yiiframework-2/

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad don't forget an upvote for answers that are helpful as this site works on this mechanism where we all benefit in finding the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@backend/views' => '@backend/themes/mytheme'],
            'baseUrl' => '@backend/themes/mytheme',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 1):

just put all your view folder in themes\mytheme

Comment: I just move view folder in mytheme,now its giving me a error: 
The view file does not exist: /home/public_html/yii2/advanced/backend/views/site/login.php