# Theme based module's views in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 Advanced Template. I have created user module inside **/frontend/modules/** directory. without theme integration, views are called from **/modules/user/views/** directory.

Currently, I have created three **different themes** inside **/frontend** directory. So I would like to access views from theme directory for **User Module**. How it would be possible?

It is possible to set layout for module by

> $this->layoutPath = \Yii::getAlias('/themes/classic/views/layouts/');
>
> $this->layout = 'userLayout';

But How views can be accessed from theme directory for module?

Please suggest possible solutions..

Comment: Did you tried setting the layoutPath and layout? It worked or you are getting some error? Please specify.

Comment: It is working for me but views are rendering from modules/view directory. I want to render views from theme directory which is in /frontend/theme/classic.

Comment: Try setting your paths with these methods: setLayoutPath() and setViewPath() For morde details check this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html

Comment: Try this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622565/yii2-theme-integration/32659605#32659605

Answer (score 2):

I found solution to my question. I have implemented following way.

Added Layout path in Module.php after init() method.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->layoutPath = \Yii::getAlias('@app/themes/classic/views/layouts/');
    $this->layout = 'userLayout';
}
```

and

added theme configuration with module views in main.php config file

```
'view' => [
        'theme' => [
          'pathMap' => [
              '@app/views' =>'@app/themes/classic/views/',
              '@app/modules'=>'@app/themes/classic/modules',
              '@app/widgets'=>'@app/themes/classic/widgets'

          ],
          'baseUrl'=>"/themes/classic",
        ],
    ],
```