# Yii2 Theme Integration not working?

Tags: yii2

Yii2 Theme Integration ?

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/admin/views'],
        'baseUrl' => '@web/admin',
    ],
],
```

Comment: What's the question, show your component code. What are you doing, what you goal we can't image what do you nedd......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622565/yii2-theme-integration

Comment: @Deepak Syal : If it is any consolation I find Yii2 theme system entirely overly complicated and not very convention based. Every time it is a headache...

Answer (score 9):

Hope you are using the **advanced template**

add a folder themes in the backend folder

make a subfolder with the theme name and make sure you have the layouts folder in that folder

ie 
your new **layout folder** path will be

**backend/themes/themefoldername/layouts**

in the folder **backend/config/main.php**

```
 'components' => [

        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@backend/themes/themefoldername',
                'baseUrl' => '@backend/themes/themefoldername',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@backend/views' => '@backend/themes/themefoldername',
                ],
            ],
        ],...
```

if you want to keep it in the web folder also you can do that,but make sure you change the path accordingly

Comment: what about if i am not using the advance template??

Answer (score 1):

In advance template there is separate configuration for frontend and backend theme integration.

Frontend theme integration => "**frontend/config/main.php**" file :

```
'components' => [ 
    'view' => [
            'theme' => [

                'pathMap' => [
                    '@frontend/views' => '@themes/frontend/views', // need to // set alias first in your bootstrap.php file
                ],
            ],
        ],
],
```

Backend theme integration => "**backend/config/main.php**" file :

```
'components' => [ 
    'view' => [
            'theme' => [

                'pathMap' => [
                    '@backend/views' => '@themes/backend/views', // need to set // alias first in your "common/config/bootstrap.php" file
                ],
            ],
        ],
],
```

While coding take care of comments and directory paths and no need to write baseUrl or basePath.

Answer (score 0):

create "themes" directory in web directory and create theme there.

then include this code in your main config file.

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/yourthemename',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => [
                        '@webroot/themes/yourthemename/views',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your web.php file.

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'class' => yii\base\Theme::className(),
                'basePath' => '@app/themes/themename',
                'baseUrl' =>'@web/themes/themename',
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which i normally use for themeing. You can set param in params file and add theme name there or directly in the below code.

```
'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@webroot/themes/themename/views'],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/themename',
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are  using yii2 basic then in config/web.php write this

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@app/themes/basic',
                'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic',
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@app/themes/basic',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the adminlte theme this be find the vendor folder,
then in the config/main.php added this:

```
'components' => [         
     'view' => [
     'theme' => [
         'pathMap' => [
            '@app/views' => '@vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app'
         ],
     ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In basic installation  under config/web.php add the code under component block.

```
'components' => [
               ................
               ....................
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => [
                '@app/views' => '@app/themes/mytheme',
                '@app/modules' => '@app/themes/mytheme/modules',
            ],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/mytheme',
        ],
    ],
 ...........
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for install theme and setup.

http://banoprogrammer.blogspot.in/2017/07/backend-theme-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

I set up a theme for my frontend using the advanced template. My themes are located in the themes folder which I created for storing the themes. eg. `web/themes/cerulean`. There are NO physical view folders under any of the individual theme folders as might be suggested by some of the key/value pairs that I have seen eg. `['@app/views' => '@webroot/themes/themename/views]`. In fact, my code runs with and without value's views subfolder. This is my working `code => @webroot/themes/cerulean` as opposed to `@webroot/themes/cerulean/views` but it does need key's `views` subfolder. ie. `@app/views`. I have tested both of these variations and they both work so do not be concerned whether you have a view on the end of the value or not.

Because I am using a theme for the frontend I have replaced `@app/views` as above with `@frontend/views`.  This is my code in my `frontend/config/main.php` file.

```
 'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@frontend/views' => '@webroot/themes/cerulean',],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/cerulean',                
            ],
        ],
```

This is the code in my `frontend\assets\appasset.php` file:

```
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

use Yii;
Yii::setAlias('@themes', Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl);

/**
* Main frontend application asset bundle.
*/
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    //public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $baseUrl = '@themes';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

You will notice above that I have substituted the

```
public $baseUrl = '@web';
```

with an alias @themes which I have set at the top namely...

```
Yii::setAlias('@themes', Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl);
```

The baseurl in the code above is now set to @themes which actually represents `@web/themes/cerulean`' taken from the `'view' => 'theme'` setting located in the `main.php` file under `frontend/config`.