# Yii 2 theming file path issues

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2 advance template for project and trying to implement theme for backend. 
To do that i have created a themes folder under backend folder as given below

  `app
  - backend
  -- themes
  --- adminlte
  ---- js
  ---- css
  ---- layouts
  ----- main.php
  ---- views
  - frontend`

To get the theme url, i am using  `Yii::getAlias('@backend/themes/adminlte/js/abc.js')` and give me full path, `/var/www/...`. But it gives me 404, page not found error even though file is present there. 
Please someone help me about file path. It will work fine if i will get path like `//themes/adminlte/js/abc.js` .

Code of config/main.php

```
'view' => [
   'theme' => [ 
         'basePath' => '@backend/themes/adminlte',    
         'baseUrl' => '@backend/themes/adminlte', 
         'pathMap' => [ 
            '@backend/views' => '@backend/themes/adminlte', 
         ], 
     ], 
  ],
```

Code of theme file(main.php)

```
<?php $themesPath = Yii::getAlias('@backend/themes/adminlte'); 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->theme->baseUrl; ?>
   /bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Please show the code where you use the alias and the echo /var_dump of the getAlias(...)  result

Comment: I am using code in main.php under the layouts folder .

Comment: If i can see the code i can evaluate otherwise no.

Comment: Code of config/main.php
<code>        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'basePath' => '@backend/themes/adminlte',
                'baseUrl' => '@backend/themes/adminlte',
                    'pathMap' => [
                        '@backend/views' => '@backend/themes/adminlte',
                        ],
            ],

        ],</code>
Code of theme file(main.php)
<code>
<?php 
$themesPath = Yii::getAlias('@backend/themes/adminlte');
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->theme->baseUrl; ?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></code>

Comment: I have formated your code. I hope correctly....

Comment: Page not found is the result of a render (or link to a page) seem is not related to this code.. Show the controller code where you try to render your view. (format the code in editing the question please..)

Answer (score 0):

`'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/adminlte',`

**baseUrl** must be in web root

```
-- app/backend/web/themes/adminlte
---- js
---- css
```

Comment: I dont want to create theme folder inside the web folder. You can check following URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622565/yii2-theme-integration , here they are creating themes folder outside of the web folder.