# Custom theme integration and layout in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am a newbie in Yii Framework and creating a first Yii based admin panel. Using different tutorials but I am unable to integrate my own theme in Yii. In my theme many forms are worked.

I want to see login form first, then back to dashboard page. Can anyone tell me when I need to change and which page I set main.php and how to include mainy dashboard pages, JS and CSS?

How can I implement these form in my application?

Comment: check this link http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/install-new-theme-in-yiiframework-2/

Comment: Go through this link once
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622565/yii2-theme-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for including your assets like css and js you should be change AppAssets in assets folder or create your own Asset class and then register your assets in your layout.
for showing login page at first you should be render your login page in SiteController>actionIndex