# I need to integrate html template into yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to apply html template into yii2 framework.
I have tried this links.[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25622565/yii2-theme-integration),[Link2](http://mehesznet.blogspot.in/2014/06/dressing-up-basic-yii2-app-with-custom.html)

But I don't get the right answer.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#layouts)?

Comment: Is the template completely created with independent files? You can always add html template files to views folder in yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your html template assets(css/js) files  to

`frontend/web/css`

`frontend/web/js`

and make your css and js file included in `AppAsset.php` 
as yii2 application gives `jQuery` and `Bootstrap` assets by default so you just need not to include that in `AppAsset.php`
finally register that Asset in `main.php` which is common for all and just run the application with your html template component.